# WPF Application initialization and finalization

Tags: wpf, initialization, finalization

I am preparing to write a WPF client application that uses ICE (Internet Communication Engine) middleware. ICE requires proper initialization and finalization. All the examples show how to accomplish this in a usual console application - which is easy because you only need try-finally block and do some stuff in it.

What about WPF? How can I be sure that some code will be called no-matter-what happens to finalize the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Application.Exit event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx)

Also, see [How to detect when application terminates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372123/how-to-detect-when-application-terminates)

Comment: Thank you. Application.Exit, as I've tested, is not called when an unhandled exception is thrown. The second link resolves that issue.