# Is there a way to get a notification, when the main thread stops in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, spring-aop, spring.net, thread-synchronization

I'm writing an application that uses a separate thread for logging.
I'd like to stop the separate thread when the main thread stops. However I'm unable to figure out when to stop the logger thread exactly as I don't know when the main thread stops. Is there a mechanism in C# that would send a notification when the main thread stops? (Or can you think about another solution to my problem?)

```
// This class automatically applies on each call of every method of Main() function
public class CommandLoggingAdvice : IMethodInterceptor
{
    private static ProducerConsumerClass LoggingQueue = ProducerConsumerClass.Instance;    
                LoggingQueue.AddTask("Logging message on call of *method*");            
}

public sealed class ProducerConsumerClass
{
    // here Iget an instance of log4net
    private ILog _Logger = null;
    protected ILog Logger
    {
        _Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger1");            
    }

    private BlockingCollection<string> tasks = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    private static volatile ProducerConsumerClass _instance;     
    Thread worker;
    private Thread mainthread;

    private ProducerConsumerClass()
    {
        mainthread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        worker = new Thread(Work);
        worker.Name = "Queue thread";
        worker.IsBackground = false;
        worker.Start(mainthread);
    }

    public static ProducerConsumerClass Instance
    {
       get
       {
            if (_instance == null)       
            {
                _instance = new ProducerConsumerClass();
            }
       }
    }

    public void AddTask(string task)
    {
        tasks.Add(task);           
    }


    void Work(object mainthread)
    {
        Thread ma = (Thread) mainthread;
        if(ma.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
             tasks.CompleteAdding();
        }
        while (true)
        {
            string task = null;
            if (!tasks.IsCompleted)
            {
                task = tasks.Take();
                Logger1.Info(task);   
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

If BlockingCollection is empty and application is still working, loop calls one more Take() and result: logger thread is paused now. So when main thread.Threadstate == Stopped, i need to kill logger thread

More info about issue were added in comments

Comment: Is "your" thread part of the same application the main thread is running?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and IsBackground = false

Comment: How exactly does your main thread terminates?

Comment: as usual... all work is done and i call return 0;

Comment: You need anything specific when stopping your logger thread, or you just want it to terminate too?

Comment: @derape Threads are not specific to app domain.

Comment: @ken2k My applicaion has IsBackground=false, in which case the logging thread doesn't terminate when the application is about to terminate. I somehow need to signal the logging thread to exit gracefully when the main thread stops.

Comment: Please add code that shows how you launch your background thread. Also this questions sound a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368697/how-to-detect-when-main-thread-terminates

Comment: @BlackFrog I've just updated the question. Please, see my example.

Comment: @hyWhy How much time do you think you would need to "gracefully shutdown"? Would it be more than a second or two?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no, logger thread is not time-dependent, it depends on blockingcollection.Count == 0 or != 0; if Count != 0 - then i catch mainthread.ThreadState == Stopped and logger thread terminates automatically after emptying the queue. But if blockingcollection.Count=0 (which means that logger thread is paused), and after that main thread terminates... - that is a problem, because logger thread is constantly paused

Answer (score 2):

You already have code in the thread that exits if the `BlockingCollection` is empty and marked as completed. Your loop checks for `IsCompleted` and exits.

What you need is some way for the main thread to call `CompleteAdding` on the collection. I would recommend a public method in your `ProducerConsumerClass`:

```
public void AllDone()
{
    tasks.CompleteAdding();
}
```

So the main thread can call `AllDone` when it's done processing. Your thread will then empty the queue and exit.

By the way, a more concise way to write your logging loop is:

```
foreach (string task in tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    Logger1.Info(task);
}
```

This also makes it easier to add cancellation support in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was the first solution in my mind, but there were an incapsulation issue: all work with blockingCollection  is focused in one place: CommandLoggingAdvice class; and also if there is one developer who only adds logging classes to one or other Program(if he is a logging specialist and his only responsibility is to write logging classes), this will cause problem to him: he would have to change program code of the Program, so there won't be independent logging classes...

Comment: About "foreach" construction - i am not sure that after "taking" last element in queue, there will be one more take, which cause pause of logging thread(so the thread wouldn't use CPU time"

Comment: And about CancellationToken... It would help me to solve the problem, but i still can not catch the moment, the place and the way, how to use it: because logging thread is paused and i am not able to call Token method from it, the mainthread is about to be terminated and i don't know how to catch any terminating events from singleton class; CommonLoggingClass is implementation of Spring.AOP framework: it is only waits for calling of functions from Main() function - so CommonLoggingClass doesn't know when mainthread being terminated.

Comment: I've tried to set Logging thread property IsBackground = true and use Singleton Dispose/Finalize methods, which in this case are being called automatically right after terminating of mainthread... And Dispose { tasks.Completeadding; worker.Join;} - there were an idea that i could force mainthread to wait background logging thread... But that doesn't work

Comment: So for now i have two so called "bad solutions" of my problem: 1) I create in the Work(object mainthread) method new parallel thread which waits until mainthread is terminated: mainthread.Join() and calls Tasks.IsCompleted() and tasks.Dispose() 2) i dont pause logging thread till the event: i use now TryTake and TryAdd, and loggingthread.sleep(250) - i pause thread on tenth of seconds and then it awakes and checks if it should be terminated

Comment: Now i am thinking about use of SynchronizationContexts... Are there any good solutions for my problem???

Comment: @hyWhy: The `foreach` I showed with `GetConsumingEnumerable` is the recommended way of using `BlockingCollection`. It does a non-busy wait for the next item, and exits when the queue is completed.

Comment: @hyWhy: Your other problem--wanting the loggers to shut down cleanly at exit without an explicit shutdown call--is a pretty typical problem indicative of an over-reliance on the Singleton pattern, which in many cases (including yours, it seems) is just a fancy way of saying "global variables." Perhaps you should have all of your loggers register themselves with a main logging class that keeps track of all loggers. The main program can then tell the main logging class that it's shutting down, and that class can then call the `Shutdown` method on each logger.

Comment: thank you for GetConsumingEnumerable method... but still there is no solution, where CompleteAdding() method should be called. About dividing one Singleton class into a lot of calls of Logger object in all classes of program... Then again the whole concept of separtion of logging concern into independent library (for example Singleton class+CommonLoggingClass) fails